# Excel formula: how do i put a sum of the true concatenation outputs at the end of the string

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, concatenation, formula

I'm trying to put a number(the sum of the true concatenations) at the end of my string in excel.

I'm using if statements with concatenate:

```
=CONCATENATE("";IF(AG$1=31;"LETTERXX, ";"");IF(AG$2=CALENDER!$K$31;"SMS xxxx xxxxxx, ";""))
```

the output now is:

`LETTERXX, SMS xxxx xxxxx,`

and the output I want is:

`LETTERXX, SMS xxxx xxxxx, 2`

can someone please help me with this?

I would be really happy.

Comment: Where are the numbers you're trying to sum. Edit your question and post a sample image of what the actual data looks like

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to add in a `sum(` at the end of your concatenate statement repeating your `IF` tests, but returning `1` when true instead.

Comment: i want to count if the concatenations i've entered are true.
So in this case there are 2 strings showing(which means the if statement in the concatenation was true) and because 2 of the if statements were true i want the number 2 to show at the end of my string

Comment: can you give me an example Plutian? I dont really use excel that much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This demonstrates what I stated in the comments, repeating your if tests (they will be done twice) and the return will be a 1 if true, nothing if false. Then all the 1's will be counted and return their sum:

```
=CONCATENATE("",IF(AG$1=31,"LETTERXX, ",""),IF(AG$2=CALENDER!$K$31,"SMS xxxx xxxxxx, ",""),SUM(IF(AG$1=31,1,),IF(AG$2=CALENDER!$K$31,1,)))
```

(I have changed some of the values so I could work with them, so please check if I have changed them back to yours correctly)

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if your issue is resolved. Also note the answer by Ron Rosenfeld, as his solution has a similar approach to mine but is slightly more elegant.

Comment: thanks i did. I do have one more small question.
Is there an easy way to get rid of the 0 if the sumis 0 of that last bit of code.

Comment: `=CONCATENATE("",IF(AG$1=31,"LETTERXX, ",""),IF(AG$2=CALENDER!$K$31,"SMS xxxx xxxxxx, ",""),IF(SUM(IF(AG$1=31,1,),IF(AG$2=CALENDER!$K$31,1,))=0, "",SUM(IF(AG$1=31,1,),IF(AG$2=CALENDER!$K$31,1,)) )` should do it. (please check for typos as I'm on mobile)

Comment: yeah i know that but thats the annoying thing. The formula gets to long lol. Can we avoid that.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't an elegant way to check for zeroes. There is for `n/a`, `erorr` etc, but not for this case, as you have fairly specific tests.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
=CONCATENATE("",IF(AG$1=31,"LETTERXX, ",""),IF(AG$2=CALENDER!$K$31,"SMS xxxx xxxxxx, ","")) & SUMPRODUCT((AG$1=31)+(AG$2=CALENDER!$K$31))
```